# Require is not defined. Object.crypto object.url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to upload a file from my react application, and after installing aws-sdk, I am having the following error:

```
external "crypto":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.crypto (external "crypto":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/uuid/lib/rng.js (rng.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/uuid/v4.js (v4.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/short-uuid/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/react-aws-s3/dist/react-aws-s3.js (react-aws-s3.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

or this one:

```
external "url":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.url (external "url":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/fromContainerMetadata.js (index.bundle.js:6294)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/index.js (index.bundle.js:6562)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist/es/index.js (tslib.es6.js:239)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sts/dist/es/runtimeConfig.js (index.bundle.js:5351)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: What does your package.json look like (if any)? And your webpack config, too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solve it by changing webpack config to

target: 'web',

[src](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/60)